# Substring index Missmatch

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
class String_pattern {
    public static void main ( String... arg )
    {
        String str = "UummbBerrrella";
        String str2 = "Umbrella";
        int j = 0;

        for ( int i=0; i < str.length(); i++ )
        {
            if ( j < str2.length() )
            {
                if( str.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j) )
                {
                    System.out.println( i + " " + j );              
                    i++;
                    j++;
                }
                else 
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }

        }
        if( j == str2.length() )
            System.out.println( " true " );
        else
            System.out.println( " false " );
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Whats the problem?

Comment: the first occurance of character " l " from the sub string miss match from the first occurance of character " l " from the give string  but it matches from the last continuous character from the given string.

Comment: index of str[11] should be match with str2[5] but it matches with str[12]

Answer (score 1):

Remove every occurrence of `i++;` from your code and it will work. Since you are using a `for` loop, with `i` as counter, it already gets incremented on every loop iteration. Adding another `i++;`. causes the loop to essetially `skip` an iteration